# How to ignore items List<T> inside Dictionary<K, List<T>> in c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have to ignore the items(List) whose product type is not contains in a given string which is inside a dictionary.

I tried to iterate the dictionary in a foreach loop and check the product type inside the loop and it works fine, but I wanted to use without iterating it, Is there anyway to achieve this?

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<PAAMsg>> FilterAllowedProductsTrades(ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<PAAMsg>> allPAA)
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<PAAMsg>> newPAA = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<PAAMsg>>();
    string productType = "BFO,BFT,BOND FWD,CAP,FEE,FEX,FRA,FUT,FxFUT,MFO,SWP,OFT,SWT";

    foreach (var item in allPAA)
    {
        newPAA.TryAdd(
            item.Key, 
            item.Value.FindAll((x => productType.Split(',').Contains(x.ProductType)))
        .ToList());
    }
    return newPAA;
}
```

I wants to avoid the below iteration and should be in a single line.

```
foreach (var item in allPAA)
{
    newPAA.TryAdd(
        item.Key, 
        item.Value.FindAll((x => productType.Split(',').Contains(x.ProductType))).ToList());
}
```

Comment: "I wants to avoid the below iteration" how are you going to do it without iterating? You could use LINQ, but not in a single line (to keep it readable) and definitively not going to avoid iterating

Comment: so you meant this code is already looks good?

Comment: It would/could be better to use LINQ to go through the Dictionary, filter it and return `ToDictionary` from that so you pass that to the constructor of `newPAA`, but not a massive improvement, and not sure if it's possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to avoid the loop, LINQ will just bury it behind its syntax. So it's a matter of preference.

One possible alternative looks like this:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<PAAMsg>> FilterAllowedProductsTrades(ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<PAAMsg>> allPAA)
{
    string productType = "BFO,BFT,BOND FWD,CAP,FEE,FEX,FRA,FUT,FxFUT,MFO,SWP,OFT,SWT";
    var productTypes = productType.Split(',');

    var enumeration = allPAA.ToDictionary(
            x => x.Key, 
            x => x.Value.Where(p => productTypes.Contains(p.ProductType)).ToList());

    return new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<PAAMsg>>(enumeration);
}
```

Also I would suggest to move `Split` operation out of the loop.

Comment: Or just make `productTypes` a constant (`private static readonly`) outside that method so the split is avoided